# Google maps how to search for places with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

i got this code but it appears when the map load, i need that by clicking in a button to hide and show the search result, can an1 help please ?

code:

```
      var map;
       var infowindow;

       function initialize() {
      var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
   center: pyrmont,
  zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
   location: pyrmont,
   radius: 500,
    types: ['store']
 };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
 }

 function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  createMarker(results[i]);
   }
   }
  }

function createMarker(place) {
 var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   position: place.geometry.location
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.setContent(place.name);
   infowindow.open(map, this);
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);\
```

EDIT

I trying to create a button that when clicked shows the search result of google places .. I hid the maker and made a function to the button show the marker, but this is not working out

```
             function createMarker(place) {
     var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
      var markersr = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       icon:icon2,
       visible:false,
       position: place.geometry.location,


                     });
```

function

```
      function showsearch() {
      markersr.setVisible(true);
       }
```

button

```
    <input type="checkbox"  name="btn2"  onClick="showsearch()"  class="btn2" >
```

Comment: why -1 ?? what i did wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the link. http://jsfiddle.net/y829C/1/

```
var mapOptions = {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                  zoom: 8,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

};
```

**Update:**

Refer the link:http://jsfiddle.net/y829C/11/

Comment: thanks but this isnt what im looking for, i have edited to make the question more clear